# Linking ports libraries under FreeBSD

Tags: compilation, linker, freebsd

I have built some libraries (`gtk3`, `qt5`, ...) through the ports collection under `FreeBSD 11.2`. In order to test them I just built minimal examples. Each time the linker complains about not finding these libraries.

Correct me if I am wrong, but under `FreeBSD`, regular packages (those which are setup with `pkg`) are installed under `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, however ports lie, by default, under `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`.

Is there a simple way to tell the compiler to search under these directories rather than having huge compilation commands with the `-I` and `-L` options?

Thank you for your answers.

### Edit

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(gtk-test)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")

find_package(GTK3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(gtk-test gtk-test.c)
target_link_libraries(gtk-test ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

I have solved the dependencies issue by grabbing the following `CMake` script:
https://github.com/eiskaltdcpp/eiskaltdcpp/blob/master/cmake/FindGTK3.cmake

However, another problem has pop up:

```
[100%] Linking C executable gtk-test
/usr/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
crt1.c:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Edit

I am stupid, I even did not notice that there was no `main` function in the sample. It works fine except that, by default, `CMake` cannot locate `GTK3` library and its dependencies.

Here is the content of my CMake config scripts:

```
Qt5         
Qt53DQuick      
Qt53DRender     
Qt5DataVisualization    
Qt5Location     
Qt5OpenGLExtensions 
Qt5QuickTest        
Qt5SerialBus        
Qt5UiPlugin     
Qt5WebKit       
Qt5XmlPatterns
Qt53DAnimation      
Qt53DQuickAnimation 
Qt5Bluetooth        
Qt5Designer     
Qt5Multimedia       
Qt5Positioning      
Qt5QuickWidgets     
Qt5SerialPort       
Qt5UiTools      
Qt5WebKitWidgets    
assimp-4.1
Qt53DCore       
Qt53DQuickExtras    
Qt5Charts       
Qt5Gamepad      
Qt5MultimediaWidgets    
Qt5PrintSupport     
Qt5Script       
Qt5Sql          
Qt5WebChannel       
Qt5WebSockets       
harfbuzz
Qt53DExtras     
Qt53DQuickInput     
Qt5Concurrent       
Qt5Gui          
Qt5Network      
Qt5Qml          
Qt5ScriptTools      
Qt5Svg          
Qt5WebEngine        
Qt5Widgets      
libxml2
Qt53DInput      
Qt53DQuickRender    
Qt5Core         
Qt5Help         
Qt5Nfc          
Qt5Quick        
Qt5Scxml        
Qt5Test         
Qt5WebEngineCore    
Qt5X11Extras
Qt53DLogic      
Qt53DQuickScene2D   
Qt5DBus         
Qt5LinguistTools    
Qt5OpenGL       
Qt5QuickControls2   
Qt5Sensors      
Qt5TextToSpeech     
Qt5WebEngineWidgets 
Qt5Xml
```

Comment: All 3rd party software is installed into `/usr/local`. But CMake should be aware about that and able to find these libs/headers. What project are you building?

Comment: @arrowd I am trying to build the Drawing Area from the gtk-demo program. This result in the following error /usr/home/hadi/Desktop/gtk-test/gtk-test.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found #include <gtk/gtk.h>. I used CMake.